# How to catch an http post abortion due to bad connection in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: http, asp.net-core-webapi, backend

I am programming a fullstack application which is used on festivals to monitor their inventory on bars (how many bottles of gin they have for instance). It allows for creating an transfer request to get more stuff to specific bar and looking up those requests. The problem arises when the connection is slow enough to cause a timeout (by my testing at 1KB/s upload/download throttle it took approx 10s) but still send the data to the API.

My method which handles writing the data to the database looks like this:

```
public IActionResult WriteStorageTransfer([FromBody] StorageTransfer transfer) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Started the execution of method");

    var transferId = database.CreateNewDoc(transfer);

    foreach (var item in transfer.items)
    {
        var sql = @$"insert into sklpohyb(idsklkarta, iddoc, datum, pohyb, typp, cenamj, idakce, idbar, idpackage, isinbaseunit)
                     values ({item.id}, {transferId}, current_timestamp, {packMj}, {transfer.typ}, {item.prodejnicena}, {transfer.idakce}, {transfer.idbar}, case when {pack.idbaleni} = -1 then NULL else {pack.idbaleni} end, {pack.isinbaseunit})";

        database.ExecuteQueryAsTransmitter(sql);
    }

    return Ok(transferId); // transferId is then used by frontend to display the created transfer request. 
}
```

This would be all nice and all, but the frontend appears to send the data to the API, API processes it and writes it to the database, but then timeout occurs on the `HttpRequest`, crashing the method, thus never returning a `HttpResponse` to the frontend (or returning code 0: 'Unknown error').

The exception thrown by the API:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.IO.IOException: The request stream was aborted.
       ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException: The HTTP/2 connection faulted.
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
         at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2MessageBody.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromStreamAsync(Stream utf8Json, ReadBufferState bufferState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAllAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object valu
e, Object container)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

The size of the JSON sent to API is usually ~10 KB, nothing too serious like 100MB so I don't think the size is the problem

This leaves the frontend hanging and the users tend to click the button again, possibly writing multiple duplicates to the database as he does not know if the invoice has been processed or if there is an error in the app.

Interestingly the `Console.Write("Started execution of the method")` does not get triggered as I do not see it in the console window, yet the data gets written into the database after manually checking it.

Perfect thing would be if I could notify the user that something went wrong in the creation of the transfer request, and prevented the creation of it in the database. I tried using `try catch` block targeted on IOException

Thanks a lot in advance, anything goes at this point

Comment: Quick Q. how many items do you normally pass in `transfer.items` when the **DB??** timeouts? As this will help get an answer. In most cases it sounds like the front end needs to catch the time out.

Comment: @Rippo added the clarification, but tldr the JSON is rather small, around 10KB usually, all of the items **DO** get added to the database, even in extreme amounts like 200 different items. As you said it might be a frontend needing to catch the timeout. Ill work on this while waiting for more answers

Comment: The IOException happens on the server side, the connection to the client is lost at that time. The Console.WriteLine() also happens serverside, so you won't see it on the client.

Comment: @CodeCaster i was looking at the serverside console, if sent over normal net the message "started execution" is clearly visible

Answer (score 0):

> The problem arises when the connection is slow enough to cause a timeout but still send the data to the API.

Back to the drawing board (or time to give us more details). If your POS app (which I assume this is) wants to report a sale to the back-end, why would the user have to wait for this? And why would the user be able to report one sale twice?

Instead have the client generate a unique transaction ID locally and store them in local storage, and (after each sale, and periodically, but most importantly: on the background) have the client try to synchronize their transactions to the server. The server can then reject duplicate transactions so it won't record the same sale twice, and your app can handle periods without or with spotty internet access.

As for your error: the timeout probably is a minute or so, which may be too long for this use case anyway. The client *will* ultimately throw an exception if it doesn't get an HTTP response, but do you want your bar person to wait on the POS for a minute? They *are* going to call it a POS then.

Comment: added further details to the question, the system isnt a POS per se, it is more like inventory manager. The solution with unique transaction ID seems very promising, will update after trying to implement